# React Native : How to get all available wifi networks in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How can I get the available list of wifi networks in iOS? Actually, I can able to connect the wifi network from iOS in react-native with the help of [react-native-wifi-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn). I am unable to get all networks in iOS. But in android, I got all things. help me resolve this. I am working on a smart home application.